# How to make queue value saved/displayed?

Tags: java, eclipse, windows-7

I'm still new on Java so didn't know how to create a good main class. On the script below, I made a sample main class for queue program. If I input it(value of Queue) manually from syntax, it saved on the program and displayed on the console. But if I input if from console, it won't be saved on the program.

```
package kelompok;

import java.util.Scanner;
import kelompok.Queue;

class QGUI{

    private Scanner inp;

    public void qgui(){
    {
        int pilih, enq, yes=0;      

        inp = new Scanner(System.in);
        Queue theQueue = new Queue(100);

        try{while (yes == 0){
        System.out.println("1. Enqueue");
        System.out.println("2. Denqueue");
        System.out.print("Masukkan perintah (1/2): ");
        pilih = inp.nextInt();


        if (pilih == 1){
            System.out.print("Masukkan queue: ");
            enq = inp.nextInt();
            theQueue.enqueue(enq);
        }
        else if (pilih == 2){

            theQueue.dequeue();         
        }
        while( !theQueue.isEmpty() )    // remove and display
        {                            //    all items
        long n = theQueue.dequeue();  // (40, 50, 60, 70, 80)
        System.out.print(n);
        System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println("");

       // end main()
}
}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("Data yang dimasukan bukan angka(Integer)!");
    System.out.println("Program harus di-restart!");
    System.exit(100);
    }
}
}
}
```

The Queue class

```
package kelompok;

public class Queue
{
private int maxSize = 100;
private long[] queArray;
private int front;
private int rear;
private int nItems;
//————————————————————–
public Queue(int s)          // konstruktor
{
maxSize = s;
queArray = new long[maxSize];
front = 0;
rear = -1;
nItems = 0;
}
//————————————————————–
public void enqueue(long r)   // letakkan item (data) di posisi belakang dari queue
{
if(rear == maxSize-1)         //
rear = -1;
queArray[++rear] = r;         //naikkan rear dan masukkan item (data) pada posisi rear yang baru
nItems++;                     //tambah satu item lagi
}
//————————————————————–
public long dequeue()         // hapus item (data) yang berada pada posisi front
{
long temp = queArray[front++]; //dapatkan nilainya dan naikkan front
if(front == maxSize)           //
front = 0;
nItems-- ;                      // item (data) berkurang satu
return temp;
}
//————————————————————–
public long peekFront()      //
{
return queArray[front];
}
//————————————————————–
public boolean isEmpty()    //benar jika queue-nya kosong
{
return (nItems==0);
}
//————————————————————–
public boolean isFull()     // benar jika queue-nya penuh
{
return (nItems==maxSize);
}
//————————————————————–
public int size()           // jumlah ietm (data) dalam queue
{
return nItems;
}
//————————————————————–
public int clear()           // jumlah ietm (data) dalam queue
{
return (nItems = -1);
}

public void Display(){
System.out.println("Isi Queue Adalah :  ");
//printing list item
for(int i=0; i<nItems; i++){
System.out.print(queArray[(front + i) % maxSize]+" ");
}
System.out.println("\n");
}//end of Display

}  // end class Queue
```

Comment: What you mean by "But if I input if from console"?

Comment: Sorry. I mean from Scanner/Keyboard.

Comment: where is your Queue class?

Comment: I edited the post with Queue class available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display queue elements once you input, then you have to add Display method inside if condition. Please check below:

```
public void qgui() {
    {
        int pilih, enq = 0;
        inp = new Scanner(System.in);
        Queue theQueue = new Queue(5);
        try {
            while (theQueue.size() < 5) {
                System.out.println("1. Enqueue");
                System.out.println("2. Denqueue");
                System.out.print("Masukkan perintah (1/2): ");
                pilih = inp.nextInt();

                if (pilih == 1) {
                    System.out.print("Masukkan queue: ");
                    enq = inp.nextInt();
                    theQueue.enqueue(enq);
                    theQueue.Display(); // Once you add if you want to display you have to add this
                } else if (pilih == 2) {
                    while (!theQueue.isEmpty()) // In dequeue remove and display
                    { // all items
                        long n = theQueue.dequeue(); // (40, 50, 60, 70, 80)
                        System.out.print(n);
                        System.out.print(" ");
                    }
                }   
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Data yang dimasukan bukan angka(Integer)!");
            System.out.println("Program harus di-restart!");
            System.exit(100);
        }
        while (!theQueue.isEmpty()) // NOTE - remove and display
        { // all items
            long n = theQueue.dequeue(); // (40, 50, 60, 70, 80)
            System.out.print(n);
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me. But queues still not displaying. When I try input a number/data into queue program, it backs to menu(1. Enqueue) without displaying queue items.

Comment: Wow Thanks a lot!! All queue items displayed correctly after I enqueue and dequeue any number/data. That's really helping.